# Seg Fault when working with strings C Program / Popen

Tags: c, linux, string, segmentation-fault, malloc

I have looked for an answer to my question for almost two days and tried every solution suggested to no avail. 
I am trying to access a file through a linux terminal using my C Program. 
I want to run `popen()` to do this.

The command I want to run in popen() is : `grep -o %s /usr/share/dict/words`

Where `%s` is a variable word that changes each iteration. I have tried using pointers, arrays, and alternative functions such as `asprintf()` / `snprintf()`

Here is the code I have right now:

```
char *message = (char *)malloc(500);
strcpy(message, "grep -n");
printf("%s", message);
strcat(message, "hello");
printf("%s", message);
strcat(message, " /usr/share/dict/words"); // SEG FAULT OCCURS HERE
printf("%s", message);
```

I would then pass this to popen.
I have also tried  initializing as: `char message[500]` and this returns the same error in the same spot.

Here is my full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "caeserheader.h"

int main( int argc, char *argv[]){

  char *inputfile;
  int n = 0;
  int shiftamount = 0;

  //Determine amount of arguments
  if(argc == 2){
   inputfile = argv[1];
   }
  else if(argc == 3){
    inputfile = argv[1];
    n = atoi(argv[2]);
    shiftamount =  n * (-1) ;
  }
  else{
    printf("Please enter a proper number of arguments.");
    return -1;
  }

  //OPENS INPUT FILE
  FILE *input = fopen(inputfile, "r");

  if(input == NULL){
    printf("\n FILE NOT FOUND.");
    perror("fopen");
    return -1;
  }

  //RESERVES MEMORY AND GRABS STRING
  fseek(input, 0L, SEEK_END);
  long Tsize = ftell(input);
  rewind(input);

  char *inputtext;
  inputtext = calloc( 1, Tsize+1);



//ERROR CHECKING
  if(!inputtext){
    fclose(input), printf("MEMORY FAILED.");
  }
  if(1!=fread( inputtext, Tsize, 1, input)){
    fclose(input), free(inputtext), printf("READ FAIL.");
  }

  //CREATES DECRYPTED STRING

  char newletter;
  char *newstring;
  int i;

  //WITH GIVEN NUMBER OF SHIFTS

  if(argc == 3){
  newstring = malloc(Tsize + 1);

  for(i=0; i<Tsize; i++){
    newletter = shift(inputtext[i], shiftamount);
    newstring[i] = newletter;
  }
  }

  //WITHOUT GIVEN NUMBER OF SHIFTS
  if(argc == 2){

 char *message = (char *)malloc(500); //SEG FAULT SOMEWHERE HERE?
    // strcpy(message, "grep -n");
    //    printf("%s", message);
    //strcat(message, "hello");
    //    printf("%s", message);
    //    strcat(message, "/usr/share/dict/words");
    //printf("%s", message);

    //    word = strtok(inputtext," ,.-!?\n");

    // int i;


       //for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        //word = strtok(NULL," ,.-!?\n");
        //printf("\n%s", word);
//}
   //  if(( fp = popen(message, "r")) == NULL){
    //perror("No file stream found.");
    //return -1;
    // }

      // else {
      // pclose(fp);

      // printf("FOUND.");
      //        }

  }

  // PUTS DECRYPTED STRING IN NEW FILE

  char copiedname[100];
  strcpy(copiedname, inputfile);
  strcat(copiedname, ".dec");
  FILE *newfile = fopen(copiedname, "w");
  fputs(newstring, newfile);

  //  free(newstring);
  fclose(input);
  fclose(newfile);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've posted should cause a segmentation fault.

Comment: Have you tried to run in a debugger to catch the crash in action? What is the values of the involved variables when the crash happens? Is the length of `message` adequate?

Comment: Also, since you don't flush `stdout` you can't be certain the crash actually happens where you think it happens, you should use a debugger for that too. Or at least add a *trailing* newline to those `printf` calls.

Comment: The code you have posted does not cause seg fault. Also note that depending on where you allocated the memory, processes in unix do not share the same namespace; therefore if one process created the array, another process cannot use the same array

Comment: In addition to the debugger suggestion, you can also try using `valgrind`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the message is plenty long enough. I am using a debugger and it seems to crash in the same part that I originally thought it was crashing.

Comment: @Smac89 all the arrays are created within main in the parent process before I call popen().

Comment: @jxh thanks for the suggestion. How do I help data from being lost? will using malloc stop this?

Comment: Have you tried to check your code with a static code analysis tool, such as cppcheck?

Comment: Where is the error happening in the full code? You have all the code that was in the original question commented out.

Comment: @Bamar I am trying to comment out different parts so I can find where it crashes.. It doesn't crash as written but as soon as I try to uncomment strcpy() or strcat() it crashes immediately.

Comment: @orbitcowboy I'm really new to coding so I don't know how to use one but I'll look into it. I'm compiling with gcc  using emacs on linux terminal. I also recently put my code into CodeBlocks so I could see any red flags but haven't come up with anything yet

Comment: `valgrind` will generate a report about what it thinks you are doing wrong in your program. If the report confuses you, try asking about how to interpret the report.

Comment: @heyjaynell No problem, you can download the app from http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/. After it is installed, you can simply let the tool check your source code in order to detect potential errors. But you must be aware that even these tools are capable of finding a few potential bugs! Good luck!

Comment: @orbitcowboy Thank you so much! found my error in deallocating a pointer.  Really appreciate it!

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you shouldn't really return `-1` from `main`. Instead return either `0` (which means success) or a value between `1` and `255` (inclusive) to mean failure.

Comment: @heyjaynell - also *note:* using `fputs` to write `newstring` to `newfile` writes *more* than `newstring` to `newfile`. Since you are reading the block of data with `fread`, it may make sense to write the same number of bytes out with `fwrite` to insure a proper conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You have set inputfile to argv[1] and later you have used strcat to append to it. Don't do this. You don't own argv.

The strcat function appends a copy of the source string to the destination string, and then returns a pointer to the destination string. It does *not* "add two strings and return the result" which is how you seem to be using it.

Comment: So instead I should should strcpy() argv[1] to a new buffer and then append ".dec" correct?

Comment: I did this but it didn't fix my segmentation fault. Thanks though

Comment: Yes, you can do that, as long as the buffer you allocate is long enough to contain argv[1] plus ".dec" plus a zero terminator.

Comment: @heyjaynell, since nothing is changing why are you not simply initializing `message[] = "grep -n hello /usr/share/dict/words";` (or making it a *string literal*)?